# Do I have to use AWS for Carrierwave to work on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave on an app on Heroku, but the pictures I upload always disappears after a few hours.  The link to the picture is still there, but it just doesn't show the picture.  I am not sure if this is the reason, but I read a bunch of posts saying Heroku is read-only filesystem so you need to change it to direct to the tmp folder instead of the public folder (per this [file](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku))

My question is, is there an alternative to using AWS as I don't want to pay to use the AWS fee for a test app. Also, I assume I also need to install the fog gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use anything that [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) supports as far as I am aware.

For instance, the README for Carrierwave lists [Rackspace Cloud](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/) and [Google Storage for Developers](https://developers.google.com/storage/) as two alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no alternative. AWS S3 is the only place to store the data. That being said the storage costs for a test app will be negligible.

Heroku does not provide a persistent file system for you. The blogs you have read are correct.

Comment: Thanks. I can't just pay for the storage, correct?  I have to pay for all the other services like Request and Data Transfer?  Also, what do the different regions mean, ie. does storing in US Region mean anything in particular?  Thanks.

Comment: It really doesn't end up costing a lot - I store GBs of data, all my website assets, my bill is usually less that $5 a month!